# Having trouble with pure CSS navigation

Tags: css, navigation

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/3A78u/

I want the sub-sub nav menu to align with the top of its parent (hence top: 0) but it aligns with the parent's parent for some reason. I'm not sure what's going on.. any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Item One</a></li>
        <li><a>Item Two</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Item two has babies</a></li>
                <li><a>Baby #2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Sub-babies</a></li>
                        <li><a>This is fun</a></li>
                        <li><a>Last Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>SubSub</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>Another Item</a></li>
                        <li><a>Another!</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    height: 40px;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* When mousing over any LI, reveal its UL if any */
#nav > ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* For all links */
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

/* Main nav styling */
#nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 1em;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: red;
}

#nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

/* Subnav styling */
#nav > ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

/* Subsubnav styling */
#nav > ul ul ul {
    left: 50px;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}

#content {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to the "level 2" `li` elements:

```
#nav > ul ul li {
    position: relative
}
```

Here's a version where the babies are all lined up: http://jsfiddle.net/3A78u/2/

If you'd like to use `>`, it would be `#nav > ul > li > ul > li`.

Comment: That works, but introduces a weird transparency issue: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/3A78u/3/

Answer (score 1):

The 'top' property is relative to the first non-statically positioned parent. In this is case it's the UL element (which is absolutely positioned). You need to add 'position:relative;' to the list-items to get elements inside to align relatively to it.